# Windows Explorer super slow for any task

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, windows-explorer

*Windows 10 x64, Windows Update enabled, everything normal.*

For some days, Windows Explorer has been *slow* for literally everything. Any action, whether it's a left or right click or anything (item, button, *scroll bar button*), or a "click in empty" to deselect an item, or a mouse wheel scroll, or anything, is always followed by the mouse pointer switching to the circular "loading" cursor for approximately 1.5sec and then back to the arrow and the action proceeds normally. (I can provide a video if needed) Obviously, using the explorer when everything has an 1.5sec delay is quite impossible.

As some posts here suggested it, I tried using Process Monitor to see what explorer.exe was up to, and ShellExView to disable *all* installed shell extensions, but it didn't change *anything* to the delay problem.

I have also tried disabling completely the Windows Search service, no effect.

I have done the standard memtest-chkdsk-sfc trifecta that the Microsoft support suggests every time you ask something on their forums.

Some people have suggested that this may be related to an HDD problem, but the problem only occurs specifically in Windows Explorer (listing files and working from cmd.exe is fast as usual) and it occurs no matter whether I am on an HDD, an SSD or even a RAM-disk.

Weirdly enough, the problem doesn't occur in other places where the Explorer "component" is used, like common file dialogs. There, browsing is blazing fast and I can double-click on a folder and it opens instantaneously.

I've been using XYplorer for a few days now and it works perfectly, although I highly prefer Windows Explorer, but it's become unuseable to the point that I don't really have other options.

I'm starting to run out of ideas, because I've tried almost everything that – I think – could be the source of this problem.

Comment: disable Realtime scanning of Defender. If this doesn't help, [capture a trace of slowness](https://superuser.com/questions/986879/windows-10s-file-explorer-very-slow-with-working-on-it/987902#comment1359396_986879)

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://mega.nz/#!OQJXXYxR!vY7r2SiWKIstAHjusFoK91Y98Iihch94L6Y4qFSSXLc
Also, the problem doesn't occur on another account, or in Safe Mode

Comment: does it happen when Malwarebytes Anti-Malware is stopped? you use an Insider Preview so some issues can occur.

Comment: it still happens even when MAM is stopped

Comment: uninstall it and also update to [Build 17704](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/), you use 17692

Comment: *oh* uninstalling worked. could you post that as an answer?

Comment: "the problem doesn't occur on another account" - While I am sure MBAM is the cause, due to the fact you were running RS5, the fact it doesn't happen on another user profile is very suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [analyzing the CPU usage](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557) of the trace with Windows Performance Analyzer, I see that every registry access involves `MbamChameleon.sys` calls.

[image]

This driver belongs to `Malwarebytes Anti-Malware`. So uninstall the tool because you run the Insider Preview `17692.1000.amd64fre.rs_prerelease.180609-1317` and 3rd party tool may not be ready for this RS5 preview version.